# How to secure terminal logout?

Tags: security

While reading about bashrc, I ran into the following fundamental problem of terminal-only machines:

If I run malicious software with a restricted account, it could edit my ".bashrc" file and set an alias to logout. The alias would point to the malicious executable and upon logout it would fake a login screen and obtain passwords to non-restricted accounts and possibly root.

While the quick solution seems to be to set "chattr +i .bashrc" as root, making the file immutable for non-root users, I don't think this is sufficient.
Shells are very complex and there might be other ways of defining aliases which I do not know about.

I thought about what the core of the issue is and to me it seems that terminal-only machines allow full control of the UI which is displayed to running software.

So one solution would be to wrap the terminal in a larger piece of UI which displays the current logged in user. This would take away some of the screen though.
Another solution would be a special reserved key on the keyboard which forces logout and cannot be re-defined by any aliases and cannot be monitored by any non-root software.

Is there some software which provides this or a similar solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key)

> A secure attention key (SAK) or secure attention sequence (SAS) is a special key or key combination to be pressed on a computer keyboard before a login screen which must, to the user, be completely trustworthy. The operating system kernel, which interacts directly with the hardware, is able to detect whether the secure attention key has been pressed. When this event is detected, the kernel starts the trusted login processing.
>
> The secure attention key is designed to make login spoofing impossible, as the kernel will suspend any program, including those masquerading as the computer's login process, before starting a trustable login operation.

On Ubuntu 12.04, it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for me.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.